# Find zeros of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix with Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, sympy, eigenvalue

Given an *N x N* symmetric matrix `C` and an *N x N* diagonal matrix `I`, find the solutions of the equation `det(λI-C)=0`. In other words, the (generalized) eigenvalues of `C` are to be found.

I know few ways how to solve this in MATLAB using build-in functions:

**1st way:**

```
function lambdas=eigenValues(C,I)
    syms x;
    lambdas=sort(roots(double(fliplr(coeffs(det(C-I*x))))));
```

**2nd way:**

```
[V,D]=eig(C,I);
```

However, I need to use Python. There are similar function in NumPy and SymPy, but, according to docs ([numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy.linalg.eig), [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html)), they take only one matrix *C*, as the input. Though, the result's different from the result produced by Matlab. Also, symbolic solutions produced by SymPy aren't helpful. Maybe I am doing something wrong? How to find solution?

---

### Example

- MATLAB:

%INPUT

```
I =

     2     0     0
     0     6     0
     0     0     5
C =

     4     7     0
     7     8    -4
     0    -4     1

[v,d]=eig(C,I)
```

%RESULT

```
v =

    -0.3558   -0.3109   -0.5261
     0.2778    0.1344   -0.2673
     0.2383   -0.3737    0.0598


d =

       -0.7327    0         0
        0    0.4876         0
        0         0    3.7784
```

- Python 3.5:

%INPUT

```
I=np.matrix([[2,0,0],
                 [0,6,0],
                 [0,0,5]])

C=np.matrix([[4,7,0],[7,8,-4],[0,-4,1]])


np.linalg.eigh(C)
```

%RESULT

```
(array([-3., 1.91723747, 14.08276253]),


matrix(

       [[-0.57735027,  0.60061066, -0.55311256],

        [ 0.57735027, -0.1787042 , -0.79670037],

        [ 0.57735027,  0.77931486,  0.24358781]]))
```

Comment: Are you sure results are not different just because the ordering/direction of the eigenvectors?

Comment: I have added an example. Of course, eig(C) either in python, either in matlab gonna output the same, but I need exactly eig(C,I)

Comment: I see I see, but just letting you know: they don't necessarily output the same, as the order and direction of the vectors/values can be different. They are mathematically the same, but the numbers can differ.

Comment: yeah, already understood, thx

Comment: Using `I` to denote a diagonal matrix other than the identity matrix is very bad notation.

Answer (score 1):

At least if `I` has positive diagonal entries you can simply solve a transformed system:

```
# example problem
>>> A = np.random.random((3, 3))
>>> A = A.T @ A
>>> I = np.identity(3) * np.random.random((3,))

# transform 
>>> J = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ii->i', I))
>>> B = A / np.outer(J, J)

# solve
>>> eval_, evec = np.linalg.eigh(B)

# back transform result
>>> evec /= J[:, None]

# check
>>> A @ evec
array([[ -1.43653725e-02,   4.14643550e-01,  -2.42340866e+00],
       [ -1.75615960e-03,  -4.17347693e-01,  -8.19546081e-01],
       [  1.90178603e-02,   1.34837899e-01,  -1.69999003e+00]])
>>> eval_ * (I @ evec)
array([[ -1.43653725e-02,   4.14643550e-01,  -2.42340866e+00],
       [ -1.75615960e-03,  -4.17347693e-01,  -8.19546081e-01],
       [  1.90178603e-02,   1.34837899e-01,  -1.69999003e+00]])
```

OP's example. IMPORTANT: must use `np.array`s for `I` and `C`, `np.matrix` will not work.

```
>>> I=np.array([[2,0,0],[0,6,0],[0,0,5]])
>>> C=np.array([[4,7,0],[7,8,-4],[0,-4,1]])
>>> 
>>> J = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ii->i', I))
>>> B = C / np.outer(J, J)
>>> eval_, evec = np.linalg.eigh(B)
>>> evec /= J[:, None]
>>> 
>>> evec
array([[-0.35578356, -0.31094779, -0.52605088],
       [ 0.27778714,  0.1343625 , -0.267297  ],
       [ 0.23826117, -0.37371199,  0.05975754]])
>>> eval_
array([-0.73271478,  0.48762792,  3.7784202 ])
```

If `I` has positive and negative entries use `eig` instead of `eigh` and before taking the square root cast to `complex` `dtype`.

Comment: yeah, matr I has only positive entries. Thanks, will try it!

Comment: @andreyxdd Cool. Just one thing (important): Do not use the `np.matrix` class! It won't work. Use `np.array` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Differing from other answers, I assume that by the symbol *I* you mean the identity matrix, *Ix=x*.

What you want to solve, *Cx=λIx*, is the so-called *standard* eigenvalue problem,
and most eigenvalue solvers tackle the problem described in that format, hence the
Numpy function has the signature `eig(C)`.

If your *C* matrix is a symmetric matrix and your problem is indeed a standard eigenvalue problem I'd recommend the use of `numpy.linalg.eigh`, that is optimized for this type of problems.

On the contrary if your problem is really a generalized eigenvalue problem, as, e.g., the frequency equation *Kx=ω²Mx* you could use `scipy.linalg.eigh`, that supports that type of problem statement for symmetric matrices.

```
eigvals, eigvecs = scipy.linalg.eigh(C, I)
```

With respect to the discrepancies in eigenvalues, the Numpy implementation gives no guarantees w/r to their ordering, so it could be just a different ordering, but if your problem is indeed a generalized problem (*I* not being the identity matrix...) the solution is of course different and you have to use the Scipy implementation of `eigh`.

If the discrepancies is within the eigenvectors, please remember that the eigenvectors are known within an arbitrary scale factor and, again, the ordering could be undefined (but, of course, their order is the same order in which you have the eigenvalues) — the situation is a little different for `scipy.linalg.eigh` because in this case the eigenvalues are sorted and the eigenvectors are normalized with respect to the second matrix argument (*I* in your example).

---

Ps: `scipy.linalg.eigh` behaviour (i.e., sorted eigenvalues and normalized eigenvectors) is so convenient for **my** use cases that I use to use it also to solve standard eigenvalue problems.

Comment: @andreyxdd Glad to have been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> D = diag(2,6,5)
>>> S = Matrix([[ 4, 7, 0],
                [ 7, 8,-4],
                [ 0,-4, 1]])
>>> (t*D - S).det()
60*t**3 - 212*t**2 - 77*t + 81
```

Computing the **exact** roots:

```
>>> roots = solve(60*t**3 - 212*t**2 - 77*t + 81,t)
>>> roots
[53/45 + (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(312469/182250 + sqrt(797521629)*I/16200)**(1/3) + 14701/(8100*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(312469/182250 + sqrt(797521629)*I/16200)**(1/3)), 53/45 + 14701/(8100*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(312469/182250 + sqrt(797521629)*I/16200)**(1/3)) + (-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(312469/182250 + sqrt(797521629)*I/16200)**(1/3), 53/45 + 14701/(8100*(312469/182250 + sqrt(797521629)*I/16200)**(1/3)) + (312469/182250 + sqrt(797521629)*I/16200)**(1/3)]
```

Computing **floating-point** approximations of the roots:

```
>>> for r in roots:
...     r.evalf()
... 
0.487627918145732 + 0.e-22*I
-0.73271478047926 - 0.e-22*I
3.77842019566686 - 0.e-21*I
```

Note that the roots are real.